# How to slice an expression in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, slice

With VHDL package `numeric_std`, a multiplication results in more bits then its operand's bits. In most cases the result will be cut to its least significant bits.

```
signal A : unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal B : unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal C : unsigned(15 downto 0);
signal D : unsigned(7 downto 0);

C <= A * B;
D <= C(D'range);
```

Unfortunately, An expression can not be sliced:

```
D <= (A * B)(D'range);
```

On the other hand, one could write a dummy function like this:

```
function dummy(A : unsigned) return unsigned is
begin
    return A;
end function;
```

Now, it's possible to chain operations:

```
D <= dummy(A * B)(D'range);
```

**Here are my questions:**

- Why can function return values be sliced, but expressions not?
- What is the technical reason to disallow chaining of operations for expressions, while function calls (btw. this is also an expression) support it?

Comment: I can propose a work around:  "C <= "*"(A, B)(D'range);"

Comment: Two questions is too broad make it one. IEEE Std 1076-2008 8. Names 8.1 para 3 "Certain forms of name (... slice names ...) include a prefix that is a name or a function call. If the prefix of a name is a function call, then the name denotes ... a slice, or an attribute, ... of the result of the function call ...", 8.5 Slice names para 3 "The prefix of a slice shall be appropriate for a one-dimensional array object...."  and 6.4.1  para 1 "An object is a named entity that contains (has) a value of a type...". Function calls are named expressions unlike chains of operations.

Comment: 9.3.4 Function calls  para 1 "A function call invokes the execution of a function body. The call specifies the name of the function to be invoked and specifies the actual parameters, if any, to be associated with the formal parameters of the function. Execution of the function body results in a value of the type declared to be the result type in the declaration of the invoked function."

Comment: My workaround is to use the `resize` function : `D <= resize(A * B,D'range);`

Comment: @Paebbels My bad ! This is what I meant. `D <= resize(A * B,D'length);`